# Redis removes all my keys immediately after BGSAVE

Tags: caching, redis

I am using redis 2.6.12 on a Windows Server x64 with configs: maxmemory 45GB, memory policy volatile-ttl (all my keys have ttl, but they never get the chance to expire, because the expire time is after a few years). Once in a day, at a certain hour, I create a dump using BGSAVE. The memory is full most of time, as I always add new keys, and the oldest keys are evicted.

The problem is that, once in a while, immediately after database saving, redis also removes all my keys and the memory drops from 45GB to 0GB, 50 000 keys to 0 keys.

Why is it happening this, and how can I save the database in background without removing all my keys ?

Here is a part of the redis.log file:

[708] 22 Jan 05:27:30.422 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45080973592 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:35.894 - DB 0: 49424 keys (49424 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:35.894 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45090250204 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:41.348 - DB 0: 49393 keys (49393 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:41.348 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45081280352 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:46.812 - DB 0: 49394 keys (49394 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:46.812 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45087803712 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:52.086 - Accepted 192.168.2.11:65374
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:52.211 - Client closed connection
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:52.274 - DB 0: 49396 keys (49396 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:52.274 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45087804476 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:57.746 - DB 0: 49397 keys (49397 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:27:57.746 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45087772152 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:03.183 - DB 0: 49365 keys (49365 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:03.183 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45089964620 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:08.637 - DB 0: 49367 keys (49367 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:08.637 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45090411120 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:14.091 - DB 0: 49393 keys (49393 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:14.091 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45091947976 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:19.550 - DB 0: 49393 keys (49393 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:19.550 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45091947976 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:25.006 - DB 0: 49393 keys (49393 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:25.006 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45091947976 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:30.443 - DB 0: 49395 keys (49395 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:30.443 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45086710236 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:35.894 - DB 0: 49453 keys (49453 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:35.894 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45090443368 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:41.388 - DB 0: 49468 keys (49468 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:41.388 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45095827040 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:46.861 - DB 0: 49512 keys (49512 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:46.861 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45095224584 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:52.293 - DB 0: 49490 keys (49490 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:52.293 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45096285456 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:57.754 - DB 0: 49505 keys (49505 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:28:57.754 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45095954716 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:03.202 - DB 0: 49393 keys (49393 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:03.202 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45086445608 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:06.962 - Accepted 192.168.2.11:65462
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:06.978 * cowBkgdSaveReset deleting 0 SDS and 0 obj items
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:06.978 - Client closed connection
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:08.634 - DB 0: 49402 keys (49402 volatile) in 65536 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:08.634 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45094333732 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:09.993 * elapsed COW DB expires time 46874
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:14.384 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105573900 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:19.853 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104530004 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:25.306 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45099816224 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:30.775 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45099575628 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:36.243 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45137384392 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:41.712 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104533564 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:47.181 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45099437328 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:52.651 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45110374948 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:29:58.120 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104543108 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:03.589 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104530980 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:09.058 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45115479704 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:14.526 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45099701388 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:19.995 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104465668 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:25.464 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45110009964 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:30.933 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45110016116 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:36.401 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104530348 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:41.870 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104530976 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:47.339 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45112236848 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:52.808 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45115479704 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:30:58.276 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45099272652 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:03.745 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104545068 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:09.214 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45110007152 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:14.683 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45115480280 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:20.151 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45104532396 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:25.620 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45099229368 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:31.089 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45130679280 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:36.558 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105333432 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:42.026 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105391176 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:47.495 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45102300088 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:52.964 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105826172 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:31:58.433 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105884184 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:03.901 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105884932 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:09.370 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45105888636 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:14.839 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45106173124 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:20.308 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45101461260 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:25.776 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45111657188 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:31.245 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45106176332 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:36.714 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45139031340 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:42.184 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45117175000 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:47.653 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45121180196 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:53.122 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 45110913708 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:54.626 * DB saved on disk
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:54.658 * Background saving terminated with success
[708] 22 Jan 05:32:54.658 * cowBkgdSaveReset deleting 49403 SDS and 99937 obj items
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:11.689 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1876072 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:17.162 - DB 0: 2 keys (2 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:17.162 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 828360 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:22.616 - DB 0: 2 keys (2 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:22.616 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 828360 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:28.064 - DB 0: 6 keys (6 volatile) in 8 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:28.064 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 830504 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:33.493 - DB 0: 6 keys (6 volatile) in 8 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:33.493 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 830488 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:38.930 - DB 0: 13 keys (13 volatile) in 16 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:38.930 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1190160 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:44.399 - DB 0: 16 keys (16 volatile) in 16 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:44.399 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1098216 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:49.852 - DB 0: 18 keys (18 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:49.852 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1099428 bytes in use
[708] 22 Jan 05:33:55.311 - DB 0: 22 keys (22 volatile) in 32 slots HT.

Any help please ?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Why don't you "build" latest version of Redis on your Windows machine?

Comment: @Manu How can I do that, can you please give me a few instructions ? I found a redis.exe ver 2.6.14, but the redis watcher service(that is responsible to keep the redis.exe process alive) used with redis.exe ver 2.6.12 is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this looks like a bug, this is what I would suggest:

- Install Cygwin (this is needed for `fork()`)
- Install [Visual Studio Express Edition 2010](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709949) (this is provided for free by Microsoft)
- Follow **instructions** on page https://github.com/dmajkic/redis and build latest **2.8.*** version.

(Note that dmajkic's fork is as old as 2.4)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try. Sorry I can't vote you answer as I don't have enough reputation.